# Grails Fixtures Plugin: How do I purge a fixture after running one test case with it?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spock, fixtures

Let's say I have a fixture defined a:

```
def fixture = fixtureLoader.load { 
    book( Book, name: "XYZ")
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
fixture.purge()
```

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: If this fixture is a class field You can purge it in `cleanup` method.

Comment: @Opal will it cleanup(remove from DB) the data created inside it?

Comment: Not sure about it, this is the place when such methods should be invoked. Don't know how it works exactly, because I'm not a grails dev. However I guess that You can invoke a kind of `flush` method after `purge` to save the state to DB.